# Disable ActionBarDrawerToggle's drawer indicator, but keep the hamburger icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation, navigation-drawer

In my main activity I'm getting references to my DrawerLayout and Toolbars like this:

```
    //Set the toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Set navigation drawer
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    hamburger = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(hamburger);
    hamburger.syncState();
```

In one of my fragments, I want to completely disable 1) swiping to open the nav drawer and 2) the hamburger/toggle button to toggle nav drawer opening

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
mainActivity.drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
mainActivity.hamburger.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mainActivity.hamburger.syncState();
```

Swiping is correctly handled - it no longer opens the drawer.

The hamburger icon has completely disappeared though. Ideally, I want the hamburger icon to remain on the screen, but to just sit in a disabled state so that it doesn't do anything when clicked. Is there an alternative to `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` that will work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably to just set a `DrawerArrowDrawable` as the toggle's Up indicator, and enable/disable the drawer indicator as usual.

After you've initialized the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, call:

```
hamburger.setHomeAsUpIndicator(new DrawerArrowDrawable(toolbar.getContext()));
```

`DrawerArrowDrawable` is actually what the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` uses for that animation, and its default state is the hamburger. When you disable the drawer indicator, it switches to the Up indicator, but that doesn't receive the drawer opening/closing calls, so it just sits in the default state. Re-enabling the drawer indicator switches back to the toggle, which does get the drawer events, so the animation is re-enabled as well.

Comment: what is `hamburger` ? (is navigationDrawer, toolbar or etc... what is it ?)

Comment: @RayVaniya I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @RayVaniya Oh, do you mean, what is the `hamburger` variable in my answer? It's the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. That's just what the OP named it in their question.

Comment: @ MikeM well i m implementing CustomNavigationDrawer with Custom ToolBar and 
i have added custom button for opening and closing drawer but the inbuilt Hamburger button is visible and i want to disable that inbuilt hamburger button, so how can i disable or hide that button.

Comment: @RayVaniya Did you use the Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio? If so, I think it automatically includes an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in the code, IIRC. Just remove all the code for that.

Comment: @ MikeM No i m not using that AndroidNavigationDrawerTemplate and in my case " removing `mDrawerToggle.syncState();` disabled/hide that inbuilt hamburger button( i dont know whether this is acceptable solution or not but for now this is working in my android studio 3.0).

Comment: @RayVaniya OK, well, it doesn't matter, then, if you're using that template or not. If you're not using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to open and close your drawer, then just don't use it. That is, remove all of the code for it. The only thing it does is put that hamburger button on the toolbar to toggle the drawer.